# Как настроить debugging сервера?

Tags: отладка, maven, intellij-idea

День добрый!

Помогите, пожалуйста, с простым вопросом:

Есть intellij idea. Есть сборка проекта через maven. Вопрос: как мне отладить собранный проект?

В Идее есть дебаггер, но он работает со сборкой через саму Идею. То есть через какой-то ее внутренний скрипт, артефакты итд. А мне удобнее собирать через Maven. Отсюда и вопрос: как мне так сделать, чтобы проект собирался Мейвеном, а дебагился через Идею?

Второй вопрос вероятно связан с первым: как сделать так чтобы Идея собирала проект моим Maven-скриптом? Я не говорю про Maven Plugin, я именно про Build в IDE. Вероятно если мне это удастся, я смогу и отладчик запустить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короче так сделал: Edit Run Configuration, там галочку "перед запуском выполнять Maven цель", в Deployment поставил размещать не артефакт, а external source - target/war. Работает, дебажит.

Думаю вопрос закрыт (правда как закрыть я не знаю).

Comment: ч-з пару дней около вашего ответа появится галочка с возможностью принять свой ответ.